# Left align one text and right align the other, but on the same line

Tags: templates

My cls file has the following

```
\newcommand{\jobentry}[5]{
    {\raggedleft\textsc{#1\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#2}{}{}{\hspace{6pt}\footnotesize{(#2)}}}\par} % Duration and conditional full time/part time text
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{}{}{{\raggedright\large #3}\\} % Employer
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#4}{}{}{{\raggedright\large\textit{\textbf{#4}}}\\[4pt]} % Job title
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#5}{}{}{#5} % Description
    \medskip % Vertical whitespace
}
```

And, in my tex file, I have the following content

```
\jobentry
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023} % Duration
    {FT} % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp} % Employer
    {Software Engineer} % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description
```

This produces the following output on the pdf.

[image]

However, I want to **ABC Corp** on left and **Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023 (FT)** on right like it is now, but I want them both to be in the same line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm going to preface this by saying I don't see a situation where #3, #4, or #5 should be blank, so I'm only going to test for #2 being blank.)

It wouldn't be too hard to adapt BanDoP's solution to the cls file and have something like `{\large#3}\hfill\textsc{#1\ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{\hspace{6pt}\footnotesize(#2)}}\\`.  (Note also that `\footnotesize` is a switch like `\large`, so you don't need `{}`.  You also don't need the `\expandafter`s.  But you do now need a `\noindent`.)  This is `\jobentryOne`.

You could emphasize that #2 is optional by using `[]` instead of `{}`, so that you could leave it out if it wasn't necessary.  This is `\jobentryTwo`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % needed for \ifstrequal
% \usepackage{xparse} % needed for \NewDocumentCommand if your TeX version isn't new enough

\newcommand{\jobentryZero}[5]{
    {\raggedleft\textsc{#1\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#2}{}{}{\hspace{6pt}\footnotesize{(#2)}}}\par} % Duration and conditional full time/part time text
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#3}{}{}{{\raggedright\large #3}\\} % Employer
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#4}{}{}{{\raggedright\large\textit{\textbf{#4}}}\\[4pt]} % Job title
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#5}{}{}{#5} % Description
    \medskip % Vertical whitespace
}

\newcommand{\jobentryOne}[5]{%
    \noindent
    {\large#3}\hfill\textsc{#1\ifstrequal{#2}{}{}{\hspace{6pt}\footnotesize(#2)}}\\
    {\raggedright\large\textit{\textbf{#4}}}\smallskip\\ % Job title
    #5 % Description
    \medskip % Vertical whitespace
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\jobentryTwo}{mommm}{%
    \noindent
    {\large#3}\hfill\textsc{#1\IfValueT{#2}{\hspace{6pt}\footnotesize(#2)}}\\
    {\raggedright\large\textit{\textbf{#4}}}\smallskip\\ % Job title
    #5 % Description
    \medskip % Vertical whitespace
}

\begin{document}

\jobentryZero
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023} % Duration
    {FT} % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp} % Employer
    {Software Engineer} % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description

\jobentryOne
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023} % Duration
    {FT} % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp} % Employer
    {Software Engineer} % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description

\jobentryTwo
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023} % Duration
    [FT] % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp} % Employer
    {Software Engineer} % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description

\jobentryTwo
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023} % Duration
    {ABC Corp} % Employer
    {Software Engineer} % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description

\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 1):

**Edited**
Like this?

[image]

For above result the definition for `\jobentry` can be much simpler. It not need to employ `etoolbox` and its `\ifstrequal` macro and any `expandafter`.

Code for `\jobentry` assumed, that all field in the command are always present (this is not clear from question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\jobentry}[5]%
{\par\medskip\setlength\parindent{0pt}
    {\raggedright\large #3}                         % Employer
        \hfill
    {\footnotesize\textsc{#1}\hspace{6pt} (#2)}\par % Duration and conditional full time/part time text
    {\large\textit{\textbf{#4}}}\\[4pt]             % Job title
    {#5}                                            % Description
    \medskip                                        % Vertical whitespace
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\jobentry%
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023}  % Duration
    {FT}                    % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp}              % Employer
    {Software Engineer}     % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description
    
\jobentry
    {Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023}  % Duration
    {FT}                    % FT/PT (full time or part time)
    {ABC Corp}              % Employer
    {Software Engineer}     % Job title
    {In this summer job I was tasked with helping eradicate pests from industrial areas. Work involved setting traps, spraying and eradication. } % Description
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `\hfill`, e.g.,

```
Jun 2021 -- Apr 2023 (FT) \hfill ABC Corp\\
Software Engineer
```

Comment: I would want to edit the cls file and not edit on the tex itself